# heroku error not updating the node modules

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js, bots

I installed Mongoose (MongoDB) and made a database and wanted to push it into Heroku. But everytime i pushed it, it was saying that `Cannot find module 'mongoose` but it was inside the github's folder where Heroku is taking all my bot's stuff. Any idea on what is causing this?

My package.json file:

[image: My package.json file]

Comment: Heroku just installs your defined dependencies. Please [edit] your question and show us your `package.json`.

Comment: There you go...

Comment: Thanks for your update. But [please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Did you actually _install_ these things locally? Does your `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` include them?

Comment: Does your error actually say "`Cannot find module 'mongoose`", including that weird single quote? What is the full error message?

Comment: Ok i didn't know that and yes package-lock.json include them and yes it does actually say "Cannot find module 'mongoose"

The full error message:

                                                 
`Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
 Require stack:
 - /app/index.js
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)`

Comment: `at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:12:19)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
}`

Comment: That traceback should be in your question, not in a comment. And now you're showing two quotes, which makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Do you see `mongoose` getting installed in your build log? Are you sure you're pushing the correct branch?

Comment: No i don't see any of my modules getting installed but they are. And yes i only have one branch so yeah. You want to see the whole heroku's build log?

Comment: But the in the build log i saw those errors:                                                                                         10 packages are looking for funding                                                                   
         run `npm fund` for details
       
                                                                                    found 6 vulnerabilities (2 low, 1 moderate, 3 high)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: So, Mr. Chris??